# HTML for optimal output in Outlook

Tags: html, email

I am unable to use CSS for this as I am disseminating this information via e-mail through a sharepoint workflow. I have tried to make this code as MS Outlook compatible as possible. (I removed all live info)

```
<!DOCTYPE: html>
<html>
<!-- variable:eHead -->
<title>Commentary</title>
<body style="margin: 0">
    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#0000CC" valign="top" rowspan="0" colspan="0"     align="center">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
                    <!-- Banner -->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;" bgcolor="#0000CC">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="500" align="center"><a href="https://Commentary"><img alt="Commentary" src="https://Bannerimagelink.png" width="475" height="110"  style="display: block; font-family: Arial; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; Img-align; center;" border="0"></img></a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- variable: eBody -->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
                            <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" valign="top">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#0000CC" colspan="2" align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-size: 32px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; letter-spacing:-2px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000; text-align: center;" border="1">New Market Commentary Available</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding: 0px 45px 20px 45px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff;" border="1">A new market Commentary has been posted to the Market Commentary Blog.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Variable: eBodyHead -->
    <table border="1" style="border-color: #0000CC; border-width: 2.5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="498">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;">
                <div align="center">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="448">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888; text-align: left;">Market Commentary:</td>
                            <td align="text-align: center; left" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;">//Title//</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888; text-align: left;">Posted By:</td>
                            <td align="text-align: center; left" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;">//ID//</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888; text-align: left;">Category:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #323232; letter-spacing:-1px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888888;">//Category//</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #323232;">To access this Market Commentary post please click on the following link:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><font color="#d25c29" style="text-decoration: none;"><a href="https://Link">Market Commentary Blog&rarr;</a></font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" style="padding:0px 0px 10px 0px">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#0000CC">
                <div align="center">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center">
                        <!-- Variable: eFoot -->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #888888; font-size: 12px; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; line-height: 18px;">Disclaimer<font style="text-decoration: none" color="#888888">E-mail</font> Disclaimer.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

- `<img>` is a void element. It should look like either `<img />` or `<img>`, not `<img></img>`.
- `Img-align` is not a valid CSS property. Your image is already being aligned by the `align="center"` on its containing `<td>`, so you can just take it out.
- You have a few `<td>`s with `align="text-align: center; left"`. This should be either `align="left"` or `style="text-align: center;"`; you can't just mix the CSS with the old-style attribute.
- Why not use a `<span>` instead of the `<font>`?

  - For that matter, why are you displaying "DisclaimerEmail Disclaimer"?

Comment: Disclaimer, email, disclaimer ------
contains specific "live" information so I replaced, sorry didnt clarify
------Thank you for your help!